# how to write expression with vb.net in mapwingis (ShapefileCategory.Expression)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I would like to give color to the map with new category. to make must make previous expression.  I've tried but still failed. What is wrong ?
Please help me.

```
 Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Add("Manual")
    Dim ad As String = "Alaska"
    Dim UniqueShape As New MapWinGIS.Shapefile
    UniqueShape = FormMain.AxMapMain.get_GetObject(idx)

    Dim af As String = UniqueShape.Table.Field(1).Name
    Const cote As String = """"

    'failed
    ' category.Expression = "[STATE_NAME] = """ + ad + """"
    'failed
    ' category.Expression = "[STATE_NAME] <> """""
    'failed
    category.Expression = "[" + af + "] = " + ad
    'failed
    category.Expression = "[STATE_NAME] = " & cote & "Alaska" & cote
    'failed
    'category.Expression = "[STATE_NAME] = ""Alaska"""

    Dim utils As New MapWinGIS.Utils
    category.DrawingOptions.FillColor = utils.ColorByName(MapWinGIS.tkMapColor.Magenta)
    sf.Categories.ApplyExpression(0)

    sf.DefaultDrawingOptions.Visible = False
    ' FormMain.AxMapMain.AddLayer(sf, True)
    FormMain.AxMapMain.Redraw()
    FormMain.AxMapMain.Refresh()
```

Comment: Can you explain "fails"? Do you get an exception or some error message?

Comment: no error message but the area(alaska) does not change color

Comment: I am confused as an example of using the expression in mapwingis use language c #

Comment: http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.8/_minimal_distance_8cs-example.html#a17 and http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.8/_point_icons_8cs-example.html#a16 and http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.8/_select_by_distance_8cs-example.html#a5

Comment: C# `"[x] = \"y\""` is the same as VB `"[x] = ""y"""`. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I do not know where the error again, I think the color is not changed because it does not find an area with the name 'Alaska'. I also discovered that using vb code but I try failed. http://mapwingis.codeplex.com/discussions/476867